# Creating Nuget package from AssemblyInfo

Tags: package, nuget, .net-assembly, assemblyinfo, assemblyversions

In my .net project, having assemblyinfo.cs file contains version as "6.22.3.00151", when I create the package using NuGet (I am using nuget cli) the final package created with version "6.22.3.151" leading 2 0's are eliminated. How can I make a nuget package with same version as of assembly?

Also I observe that though my assemblyinfo.cs contains below information for AssemblyFileVersion,

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.11.0.00152")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.11.0.00152")]

after compilation I can see [image]

So even though AssemblyFileVersion is having 00152 why its showing only 152. What should I do so that it looks 00152?

Answer (score 0):

Since NuGet 3.4, NuGet normalizes all version numbers based on the scheme described here https://docs.nuget.org/create/versioning. Essentially leading zeros are trimmed as described in the document. I don't believe there is a way to workaround this unless you write your own pack.